# Doing an if else condition match in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone suggest how I might achieve the following using xslt?

This is the xml input:

```
<output>
    <header>
       <someId>ABC123</someId>
 </header>
 <results>
  <product id="A">
   <externalId>XYZ666</externalId>
   <title>some title a</title>
  </product>
  <product id="B">
   <externalId>ABC123</externalId>
   <title>some title b</title>
  </product>
  <product id="C">
   <externalId>666777</externalId>
   <title>some title c</title>
  </product>
 </results>
</output>
```

What I need is an xslt which will return only the "product" which has a \product\externalId that matches \header\someId where there is one, otherwise it matches all \product elements.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<xsl:when test="condition">` ..

For your XML I have provided sample XSLT code to select the nodes conditionally ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="results/product">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="externalId = /output/header/someId">
        <!--Here goes the code-->
        <something></something>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--Other code -->
        <somethingelse></somethingelse>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code behaves like ..

```
if ("externalId = /output/header/someId") then
        <!--Here goes the code-->
        <something></something>
else
        <!--Other code -->
        <somethingelse></somethingelse>
```

Using Indentity template override!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="results/product[externalId = /output/header/someId]">
    <!--Here goes the code-->
    <something></something>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="results/product[externalId != /output/header/someId]">
    <!--Here goes the code-->
    <somethingelse></somethingelse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as this -- no variables, no `xsl:chose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwise`**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*[header/someId]/results/product[externalId=/*/header/someId]
     |
      /*[not(header/someId)]/results/product
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<output>
    <header>
       <someId>ABC123</someId>
 </header>
 <results>
  <product id="A">
   <externalId>XYZ666</externalId>
   <title>some title a</title>
  </product>
  <product id="B">
   <externalId>ABC123</externalId>
   <title>some title b</title>
  </product>
  <product id="C">
   <externalId>666777</externalId>
   <title>some title c</title>
  </product>
 </results>
</output>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<product id="B">
   <externalId>ABC123</externalId>
   <title>some title b</title>
</product>
```

**When the same transformation is applied to this XML document:**

```
<output>
 <results>
  <product id="A">
   <externalId>XYZ666</externalId>
   <title>some title a</title>
  </product>
  <product id="B">
   <externalId>ABC123</externalId>
   <title>some title b</title>
  </product>
  <product id="C">
   <externalId>666777</externalId>
   <title>some title c</title>
  </product>
 </results>
</output>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<product id="A">
   <externalId>XYZ666</externalId>
   <title>some title a</title>
</product>
<product id="B">
   <externalId>ABC123</externalId>
   <title>some title b</title>
</product>
<product id="C">
   <externalId>666777</externalId>
   <title>some title c</title>
</product>
```

**Explanation**:

We use a generic way to select one node-set (by the expression `Exp1`) when a given condition `someCondition` is `true()` and to select another node-set (by the expression `Exp2`) when the same condition is `false()`.

The two expressions being union-ed each can select a node under two, mutually exclusive conditions, therefore, depending on the value of their condition, only one of the expressions can select a node.

```
 Exp1[someCondition] |  Exp2[not(someCondition)]
```

Comment: I prefer Identity override rather!! :)

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind', Compactness (shorter and having less number of lines/moving parts) is one of the requirements of the DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself") principle, which is the "D" in the SOLID programming paradigm. This is also mandated by the KISS ("Keep It Simple, Stupid") principle. The benefits are better readability and understandability, much less vulnerability to errors and easier maintainability.

Comment: agreed! I would like add this point: `copy-of select="Node()"` doesn't bother about template override! (example: In the above code if I add `<xsl:template match="/output/results/product/title[.='some title b']"/>` it doesn't get executed at all!!)

Comment: so depending on the requirement we can switch to template-override or copy-of accordingly .. correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind', I would always prefer the XPath expression as shown in my answer. As for `copy-of` vs. `xsl:apply-templates` -- your argument is correct. I am using `xsl:copy-of` only to output the result of the evaluation -- of course, if this result is needed only internally, one wouldn't copy it to the output. What is important here is the XPath expression. How it would be used depends on information that the OP hasn't given to us, and which isn't necessary because it would shade the generality of this question.

Comment: Yes. OP doesn't need Template-override .. agreed with your points!! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials on w3schools is a good start point!

Try to take a look on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp) page!

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools, which is widely disliked across StackOverflow (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="product" use="externalId"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="ref" select="key('by-id', //header/someId)"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$ref">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$ref"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//product"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

shows how to use a key to cross-reference the nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo in the `match` pattern, I will correct that now.